# Calculating distribution of pixel values in an image

Tags: python, image-processing, astronomy

I have a matrix of complex entries (it is the Fourier transform of an image. I shall refer to this as "signal", following the convention in radio astronomy). I'd like to calculate how the **amplitude** of the signal varies as a function of **distance** from the center of the signal, given the signal values as a matrix. Here, distance is the L2 norm of the index and amplitude is the norm of the signal values at that distance.

I am clueless as to how to get started with the problem - I keep hitting dead ends. A solution would be very helpful.

Comment: There is a whole circle of values at a given distance from the center, hence no "function".

Comment: ... hence no single value at that radius, but an entire circle of values. so you need to think about how you wanna reduce that dimension. -- I don't see the challenge here. use numpy, scipy, skimage, OpenCV, ... to work on your data. -- please review [ask] and possibly [mre] (and take the [tour]). you could at least dump some data but your own attempt at a solution is also expected. -- and... your name looks familiar. keep the one account, don't delete and recreate.